# Can I define an interface for every property of an object just the one time?

Tags: typescript

Here's my property where the interface is defined multiple times:

```
    ExamStatusId = {
        All: <IEnumElement>{
            id: this.examStatusSelectId,
            text: 'Exam Status: All',
            val: 0
        },
        Current: <IEnumElement>{
            id: this.examStatusSelectId,
            text: 'Exam Status: Current',
            val: 1
        }
    }
```

Here's the interface that I have:

```
interface IEnumElement {
    elem: string;
    text: string;
    val: number
}
```

Is there any way that I can avoid having to specify the interface after every property of ExamStatusId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't included the `elem` property, so you need to do that (although this is tangential).

My recommendation is that you embrace the wonder of type inference, and do this:

```
interface IEnumElement {
    elem: string;
    text: string;
    val: number
}

class Exam {
    private examStatusSelectId: number;

    ExamStatusId = {
        All: {
            id: this.examStatusSelectId,
            elem: '',
            text: 'Exam Status: All',
            val: 0
        },
        Current: {
            id: this.examStatusSelectId,
            elem: '',
            text: 'Exam Status: Current',
            val: 1
        }
    }
}

// This function must be passed an IEnumElement
function example(element: IEnumElement) {

}

var exam = new Exam();

// The compiler knows this is good
example(exam.ExamStatusId.All);
```

If you didn't include the correct properties when you declared the `ExamStatusId` property on your class, the compiler would correctly detect the problem and tell you about it, because it will compare the best common type in the `ExamStatusId` with the `IEnumElement` interface (so even if you only missed `elem` off of one, you'd get the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is possible with an extra interface like the code below. The generic IIndexable interface makes it also easy to use on different places!

```
interface IEnumElement {
    elem: string;
    text: string;
    val: number
}

interface IIndexable<T> {
    [index: string]: T;
}

var ExamStatusId: IIndexable<IEnumElement>  = {
    All: {
        elem: "",
        text: 'Exam Status: All',
        val: 0
    },
    Current: {
        elem: "asdf",
        text: 'Exam Status: Current',
        val: 1
    }, 
    X:  {} // this is now an error!
}
```

edit: The nice thing about using the interface is that you will get autocompletion too!

Comment: The issue with this is that he loses access to *which are the valid members* of `ExamStatusId`. These should only be All,Current or any other that he explicitly types

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon your purpose. If your purpose is to get the intellisense + type checking when accessing members of the Object as shown below:

[image]

**And** you want the intellisense + type checking when creating the individual members:

[image]

Then the solution you have is the best one I can think of.